# Не работает header() после submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

В общем буду краток у меня проблема. При заполнении в форме username и выбора товара в option
и нажатии в дальнейшем submit ничего не происходит просто обновляется страница и все. Хотя раньше все работало  вот код формы

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="goods" id="srv" name="srv">
    <div class="block-1">
        
        <input type="text" class="toggle d-block" placeholder="Ник на сервере" name="username"/><br>

        <select id="groupbeta" name="group">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Выберите привилегию</option>
            <?php foreach($config['cats'] as $k => $v): ?>
                <optgroup label="<?=$v?>">
                    <?php foreach($config['anarchy'] as $r => $p):
                        if ($p['cat'] == $k) {?>
                            <option value="<?=$r?>"><?=$p['name']?> - <?=$p['cost']?> рублей</option>
                        <?php } endforeach;?>
                </optgroup>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" class="qiwi" name="qiwi" id="qiwi" value="Оплатить через QIWI"/>
        <input type="submit" class="buy" name="buy" id="buy" value="Оплатить"/>
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
```

PHP Код

```
if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['nickname']));
$group = trim(strip_tags($_POST['group']));

if (!empty($name)) {
    if (!empty($group)) {

        include 'engine/payment.class.php';
        $pay = new payment();

        $price = $config[$_POST['srv']][$group]['cost'];

        if($surcharge && $config[$_POST['srv']][$group]['surcharge'])
            $price = intval($price - $surcharge);

        header('Location: '.$pay->pay_form($price, $name, $group, $_POST['srv']));
```

Answer (score 0):

У форме у вас input:

```
<input type="text" class="toggle d-block" placeholder="Ник на сервере" name="username"/>
```

Но в php `name="username"` вы принимаете как `$_POST['nickname']`, потому вы не попадаете в условие и ничего не работает. Определитесь с названием

Comment: Спасибо исправил но все-же не работает.

Comment: значит смотрите что куда попадает и что pay_form() возвращает